# What can happen if I try to charge lead acid battery outside charger's capacity range?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, safety, lead-acid

I'm looking for lead acid battery charger. My battery (originally from UPS) has 12V and about 40Ah capacity. This is what I see in one charger's datasheet:

> Automatic charger for sealed lead acid batteries 2 V up to 24 V with the capacity range from 2.4 
>   **Ah to 24 Ah**.

Actual capacity of my battery is definitelly lower than what it says on the seal, but still it's clearly out of range. Is that actually problem? If so, why?

Comment: It completely depends on how the charger has been implemented. I'd guess that the charger being "automatic" is microcontroller controlled. It thus probably has a charging timeout and/or a charge (Ah) limit, so it might stop charging prematurely, but I wouldn't expect anything *bad* to happen.

Comment: You can charge SLA batteries with 13.6 V continuously and charging will stop "automatically" when the battery has also reached 13.6 V. You could call that "automatic" with no controller needed. So probably there is no microcontroller. It actually does not matter much what the capacity of the battery is as long as it is an SLA type and not below 2.4 Ah as then the charge current might get too large when the battery is empty.

Comment: Some just have a timeout so if the battery capacity is too large, you have to reset the charging in order to charge it fully.